# Check if an element exists in Ansible

Tags: ansible

In my Ansible role I have:

```
rcube_plugins_repo:
    - name: 'account_details'
      repo: 'https://github.com/texxasrulez/account_details'
      config: 'yes'
    - name: 'delete_old'
      repo: 'https://github.com/ron4mac/roundcube_delete_old'
and so on...
```

In one of my task, I need to check if `account_details` exists in `rcube_plugins_repo`

How do I do that?

I thought about something like:

```
when: "rcube_plugins_repo.name['account_details'] is defined"
```

But it doesn't work and I'm sure how to correctly write this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rcube_plugins_repo` is a list of `dict`, so `rcube_plugins_repo.name` would not work in the first place. Even if you got a value with that, you would have had to compare to account_details, not checking for a `account_details` subelement.

[`selectattr`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#selectattr) filter allows you to filter a list of dicts according to a filter. Here you'd like to filter on the value of the name attribute.

I tried the following with, it seems to work:

```
 when: "{{ rcube_plugins_repo|selectattr('name', 'eq', 'account_details')|list }}"
```

If the filtered list is empty, the condition will not be met.